# How can I convert a Mercurial repository to Git (with LFS support)?

Tags: git, mercurial, git-lfs

I have a Mercurial repo with 300-some commits in it that also contains a number of relatively large (say 10+ MiB) files. I'd like to convert this to a Git repository, keep all of the branches and merges, and also use the LFS extension to manage the big files. Here's my process thus far:

1. Clone the Hg repo from its server using `hg clone <URL>`
2. Create a new git repo somewhere else with `git init`
3. `cd` into the git repo, then convert with `hg-fast-export -r <hg-repo> -A <authors>`. At this point, I have a working repo, but all the big files are still part of the index. I want to wedge a new commit in "before" anything else to insert `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` files.
4. Make a new, empty branch with no parent commit: `git checkout --orphan new-root && git rm -rf .`
5. Create the two files and commit them to the new branch. `git add * && git commit -m "Check in git metafiles"`
6. Now my "new" root commit is ready to go, so I try to uproot the whole thing: `git checkout master && git rebase --root --onto new-root --preserve-merges`

And this is where I'm stuck. The rebase gets about 10 commits in before dumping this error on me.

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        assets/ui/sayscreen/blackarrow.png
        assets/ui/sayscreen/blackcircle.png
        assets/ui/sayscreen/thoughtbox.png
        assets/ui/sayscreen/translationbox.png
        assets/ui/sayscreen/whitearrow.png
        assets/ui/sayscreen/whitecircle.png
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
fatal: cherry-pick failed
Could not pick 01908b624e50709de07685ef8ab158feef02e9e0
```

What's really confusing me here is that, in the original Hg repository, there is no merge at this point; the first merge commit is at 15. In addition, running `git status` lists 50-60 modified files, even though this particular commit only touched 8 files originally. Finally, using `git ls-files -u` to try and see what files are conflicted returns nothing.

Since most of the files listed by `git status` are PNG images, my first thought was that LFS was somehow getting in the way and trying to pull out the large blobs during the rebase. However, I ran `git lfs uninstall` in a global context before starting this whole process, with the intent of doing `git lfs migrate import --fixup` after I was satisfied with the rebase operation.

What's causing these merge conflicts, and how can I get around it to finish the migration?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the source of the problem, but in general, preserve-merges (or even its better / fancier new cousin rebase-merges) *can't* actually preserve merges. It has to *re-perform* them. The whole approach is bristling with potential failure points. It's probably better not to attempt to rebase. I have zero experience with `git lfs migrate` and I don't know what you intend for these attributes files, but you could stuff them in after the import, before the migrate, using `git filter-branch` rather than rebasing. If possible though, don't bother!

Comment: I'm not a git person but here's an HG approach -- you could insert your .gitignore and .gitattributes files on the HG side of things first, and then bring them in with the export from hg to git. More than one way to do this, but for full control you could use hg convert with the --splicemap option.

Answer (score 1):

I just converted to git from a mercurial repo extended with large files recently. Here are some points.

1. You have to convert the mercurial repo to a "normal" one at first.
2. When doing "hg clone", better to pull all large files to local.

---

```
$hg clone <hg-repo>
$hg -v lfpull --rev "all()"
$cd ..
$hg lfconvert --to-normal <hg-repo> <hg-repo-nolf>
... // verify the repo
$hg-fast-export -r <hg-repo> -A <authors>
```